# How to check if a list contains duplicate items?

Tags: python, validation

I want to validate a list to make sure that there are no duplicate items. My problem is that I don't know how to do this in the if statement. Is there a method or something in python that will return False if there are duplicates in the list?

Here is what I had in mind:

```
lst = ["1","2","3","3","4"]

if #lst contains no duplicates :
    print("success")
else:
    print("duplicate found")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As said by Jkdc, convert it to a set and compare the length

```
lst = ["1","2","3","3","4"]

if len(set(lst)) == len(lst):
    print("success")
else:
    print("duplicate found")
```

Comment: This doesn't work when `lst` is a list of dictionaries. `set(lst)` then throws a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Answer (score 8):

Exploit the Fact that Python `set` may not contain duplicates. The `has_duplicate()` Function takes care of determining if a list contains duplicates.

```
def has_duplicates(listObj):
    return len(listObj) != len(set(listObj))


print(has_duplicates([1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7]))    ## PRINTS: True
print(has_duplicates([9, 2, 5, 4, 7]))       ## PRINTS: False
```

Comment: you can simplify to `return len(listObj) != len(set(listObj))`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, the easiest way (at least for me)..

```
lst = ["1","2","3","3","4"]
status = True
for item in lst:
    if lst.count(item) > 1:
      # the count functions counts how many times the "item" is in lst
        status = False

if status == True:
    print("No duplicates")
else:
    print("Duplicates found")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_duplicates(lst):
    seen = {}
    for item in lst:
        if seen.get(item):
            print("duplicate found")
            return
        else:
            seen[item] = True
    print("success")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkDuplicate():
    count = {}
    for item in lst:
            if item not in count:
                count[item] = 1
            else:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.