# seeing if there are multiple instances in a list

Tags: python

What I have tried is

```
answer = "'You need to enter one alphabetic character which you haven't\
already guessed. Try again'"

counter = 0

p = [x.lower() for x in past_guesses]

if len(p) != (set(past_guesses)):
    result = answer
else:
    result = 'Good guess'
return result
```

As expected any duplicate letters should fail, returning the answer, and any that don't contain duplicate letters should pass, however for the *input ([A, b])* I am getting the return for a duplicate.

Anyone know why and how this can be fixed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "input" - there is neither a stdin input, nor is it a function with parameters... but I believe you might be missing a `len` in your `if`?

Comment: should there be a len in front of (set(past_guesses))?

Comment: More specifically, you probably want this `if len(p) != len(set(past_guesses)):`

Comment: Even then im getting the same answer, for past_guesses i input (['A', 'b']) and got answer instead of 'Good guess'

Comment: Works fine for me (I see "Good guess"): https://trinket.io/python/638e377cf1

Comment: Oh i see my mistake, i need to set it to the changed list not the original list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a list contains duplicate items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209673/how-to-check-if-a-list-contains-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lacking place in if condition. You are trying to compare the length of set and list but unfortunately you have forgotten.

Add len() to your code:

```
if len(p) != len(set(past_guesses)):
```